# json на laravel api

Tags: json, laravel, api

Изучаю Laravel.
Попытался через контроллер получить и обработать json.
Json отправляю через Postman. Получил код 419. В чем может быть ошибка?

Код контроллера

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResponseController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
      return $_GET['name'];
    }

    public function response()
    {
      return
      $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
      $data = json_decode($json, true);
      print_r($data);
    }
}
```

файл api.php

```
Route::post('/test1', 'App\Http\Controllers\ResponseController@response');
```

Comment: Кроме кода возвращается текст ошибки, посмотрите. А вообще `419 Page Expired (Laravel Framework) Used by the Laravel Framework when a CSRF Token is missing or expired.`. То есть нет токена CSRF. Если пишите API, токен CSRF не надо использовать. А 419 вам дает мидлварь 'web', которая прописана в `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`. Кроме этого, в вашем коде просто все надо переделать, начиная с `api.php` - новая Лара использует уже другую нотацию, кончая `$_GET` и `file_get_contents`. Если делаете по какому-то уроку, то этот урок устарел и плохой. Если не делаете - посмотрите.

Comment: @TotalPusher смотрел несколько видеоуроков, некоторые мартом этого года датированы. $_GET и прочее использовал просто ради проверки, работает или нет. Но в целом я пока не знаю методов базовых классов, чтобы через них работать. Если подскажете какие-то видеоуроки или еще что-то, кроме документации - буду благодарен.

Comment: 1. Используйте более новую нотацию: `Route::post('/test1', [App\Http\Controllers\ResponseController::class, 'response']);` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtZ4b_6kVVI 2. Для создания контроллера для API используйте команду `php artisan make:controller ResponseController --api` а в `api.php` `Route::apiResource("/test1", App\Http\Controllers\ResponseController::class);` 3. В методах контроллера используем по такому типу `public function index(Request $request)` или даже передаем модель `public function update(Service $service)` - лара создаст ее сама!

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/441946/ - более менее урок. По 419 ошибке - возможно что в постмане не указали заголовок `Content-type: application/json`. Или что-то поломали в `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` или `Kernel.php`, потому изначально все должно работать. Или забыли указать `/api/test1` в адресе и слали на `/test1`.